# What package must I load to use \ElsevierGlyph?

Tags: packages

I have a document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ElsevierGlyph{E25E}
\end{document}
```

but it errors out on the `\ElsevierGlyph{E25E}`. What package must I load to have these available?

Comment: There are only very few mentions of that command online. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xmltex/contrib/passivetex/unicode.sty (https://github.com/sebastianrahtz/passivetex/blob/master/unicode.sty) suggests the command comes from or is heavily associated with a file called `elfonts.sty`. I doubt this command is used actively by many people these days.

Comment: loading elfonts, unicode, or both doesn't help for compilation. There's quite a few unicode -> latex mappers (like mine) that reference it, but if it's deprecated, looks like I'll have to find replacements for the ElsevierGlyph commands. If you paste your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only very few mentions of the command `\ElsevierGlyph` online. Most are from some Unicode-LaTeX converters. The only TeX-code mentions that I could find was http://gmirrors.ctan.org/macros/xmltex/contrib/passivetex/unicode.sty (see also https://github.com/sebastianrahtz/passivetex/blob/master/unicode.sty). That suggests that the command comes from `unicode.sty` of the `passivetex` package for XML/XSL processing (according to the readme, `passivetex` has been dormant since 2003 and the developer passed away about three years ago). The command `\ElsevierGlyph` seems to be associated with `elfonts.sty`, another package that I couldn't track down any further. (So even with `unicode.sty` loaded, `\ElsevierGlyph` won't work as expected on my MikTeX system with on-the-fly installation enabled.)

I doubt that any of the packages are actively used by many people in LaTeX documents nowadays. (So especially if this is for a Unicode-LaTeX mapper I would not rely on users having access to `\ElsevierGlyph`.)